# ActivityNotFoundException on TextView with autoLink="web"

Tags: android

How to catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` if a `TextView` gets clicked because it displays a website?

If a device doesn't have a browser than it throws that exception.

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTextView"
    android:autoLink="web" />
```

Java:

```
TextView tvTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTextView);
tvTextView.setText("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if there is an Activity to handle your Intent with the following :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if (infos.size() > 0) {
    //At least one application can handle your intent 
    //Put this code in onCreate and only Linkify the TextView from here
    //instead of using android:autoLink="web" in xml
    Linkify.addLinks(tvTextView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    // or tvTextView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URL), as suggested by Little Child
}else{
    //No Application can handle your intent, notify your user if needed
}
```

Comment: If an `intent` can be created by the OP, then `startActivity()` can be surrounded by try-catch. :) OP says that it is out of his control. :)

Comment: `Linkify.WEB_URLS` must be used, AFAIK. :), in the `onCreate()`

Comment: @LittleChild Read my comment below your answer, I am *not* calling `startActivity()` by myself.

Comment: I removed the bit about calling startActivity to set it right ;)

Answer (score 2):

Surround the `startActivity()` in `try-catch` block. That's all.
Your `catch` will handle the `ActivityNotFoundException`.

**Update based on 2Dee's answer:**
What should be done is that instead of using `autoLink:web` in XML, the OP must first create an intent to open a website, say Google. While in `onCreate()`, see if there is an `Activity` to handle it. If yes, retrieve the `TextView` and call the `setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URL)`

**Code Snippet:**

```
Intent checkBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
checkBrowser.setData("http://www.grumpycat.com");
List<ResolveInfo> info = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(checkBrowser,0);
if(info.getSize() > 0){
    TextView  tv = (TextView) findElementById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URL);
}
```

Comment: Can't, it handles it all by itself, I'm not calling anything, I only set the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to check if the browser is available

```
public boolean isBrowserAvailable(Context c) {

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData("http://www.google.com");//or any other "known" url
        List<ResolveInfo> ia = c.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        return (ia.size() > 0);


}
```

and then, in `onCreate`, you decide if make it autolinkable or not.

```
    if (isBrowserAvailable(this) 

          tvTextView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URL)
```